# Reactjs key warning even key is set

Tags: javascript, reactjs

console shows this warning even key is set on the child component:

```
bundle.js:2215 Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop
```

code so far:

```
 var requestList = this.state.data.map(function (request,index) {
            return (
                <Requests key={request.id}  info={request} index={index}  trigger={this.triggerChildRequests}></Requests>
            );
        }.bind(this));
```

Comment: It also needs to be unique, is request.id always unique?

Comment: If it's not unique you get a different error: "Encountered two children with the same key"

Comment: could you provide us the code of your request component?

Comment: key is unique @AntonisZisis

Answer (score 2):

Maybe `request.id` is undefined, try to use `index` as component's key.

```
var requestList = this.state.data.map(function (request,index) {
            return (
                <Requests key={index}  info={request} index={index}  trigger={this.triggerChildRequests}></Requests>
            );
        }.bind(this));
```

Comment: Using `index` as keys it's not a good idea for uncontrolled components.

Comment: @Ursus I don't think so, once the key is unique, that's done.

Comment: @DavidGuan not sure about that https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318#.2x9stgach

Comment: @Ursus `It looks elegant and it does get rid of the warning (which was the ‘real’ issue, right?).` The problem has been solved in latest react, if we using index as key now, that's okay.

Comment: @DavidGuan I didn't know that, thanks. Any link to back that up?

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html#keys  `Remember that the key only has to be unique among its siblings, not globally unique.`